# Erro Cannot read property ' toString ' of undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, express.js

Estou criando uma aplicação fazendo uso de [Express](http://expressjs.com/pt-br/), porém estou enfrentando esse erro :

```
➜  Futiba git:(master) ✗ node index.js

➜ [ Server ] Online

/home/akira/Downloads/Futiba/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/execute.js:57

          var str = this.parameters[i].toString();
                                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
    at Execute.toPacket (/home/akira/Downloads/Futiba/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/execute.js:57:40)
    at Execute.start (/home/akira/Downloads/Futiba/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/execute.js:53:40)
    at Execute.Command.execute (/home/akira/Downloads/Futiba/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:40:20)
    at Connection.handlePacket (/home/akira/Downloads/Futiba/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:515:28)
    at Connection.handlePacket (/home/akira/Downloads/Futiba/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:521:12)
    at PacketParser.onPacket (/home/akira/Downloads/Futiba/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:94:16)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (/home/akira/Downloads/Futiba/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:77:14)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/akira/Downloads/Futiba/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:102:29)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
➜  Futiba git:(master) ✗
```

Ao tentar adicionar valores nos inputs de `localhost:3000/admin/games`. Pesquisei aqui no fórum, porém a maioria dos tópicos que encontrei tinham em seus logs à informação de onde o erro se encontrava, nesse caso ele não informa especificamente e não estou conseguindo rastrear ainda que tenha achado algo parecido em [Why do I get Cannot read property ' toString ' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41438656/why-do-i-get-cannot-read-property-tostring-of-undefined), mas novamente, eu não estou fazendo uso de `toString` e não seria legal editar isso no pacote [Mysql 2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) que eu presumo que esteja fazendo uso dessa função, ou seria ainda que provavelmente o erro se encontra no código da minha aplicação ?

Obs : projeto [Futiba](https://github.com/sphinxs/Futiba) no Github e quando aciono o input ' salvar ' ele me envia a seguinte mensagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você poderia colocar um snippet (pedaço) do código para nós avaliarmos, por favor? Provavelmente, `this.parameters[i]` não existe (está undefined) por causa que o índice **i** está fora do intervalo do tamano de **this.parameters**

Comment: Essa feature está relacionada a esses dois arquivos : https://github.com/Sphinxs/Futiba/blob/master/admin.js#L41 e 
 https://github.com/Sphinxs/Futiba/blob/master/views/admin/games.ejs#L95 ( Ps, coloquei âncora pra ir direto pra parte do código que acho que o erro está )

Comment: Verifiquei os códigos, o erro pode estar em [game.game_id](https://github.com/Sphinxs/Futiba/blob/master/admin.js#L64) ou em [guess.id](https://github.com/Sphinxs/Futiba/blob/master/admin.js#L95). Um desses 2 itens está retornando undefined. Tente debugar essas variáveis.